# Why am I seeing multiple sets of records updated?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-update

I am running a simple update query:

```
update mtvnpm..tb_appraisalyeargroup
set annuallockstatus = 1 where appraisalyear < 2015 and annuallockstatus = 0
```

and seeing this result:

```
(43 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
```

I did recently add a trigger to a table, but it wasn't this one. I can't say for sure about the timing, but it seems like I've been seeing the extra "(1 row(s) affected)" since about the time I added the trigger on the other table.

I triple checked and there is no trigger on the table being updated here though. As mentioned above, I've been seeing this on some other updates I've done recently as well on tables that also do not have triggers on them.

How can I go about finding out where this is coming from?

Comment: Are you sure there are no triggers on that table? What does this return?  select *
from mtvnpm.sys.triggers tr
join mtvnpm.sys.tables t on t.object_id = tr.parent_id
where t.name = 'tb_appraisalyeargroup'

Comment: You can also check out the execution plan when you run that query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turning on "Include Actual Execution Plan" in Management Studio will cause an extra "1 row affected" message to be returned. This is because the query plan is returned as a row of XML data in a second data set.

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer but I don't remember what the silly requirement is to allow to post a comment.

Comment: Thanks. Don't think that was the case for me but it's good to know that there are other things that can cause this.